# spring boot to mysql docker communcation

Tags: java, mysql, docker, spring-boot

I have created a `spring boot` app. When I run the app inside Eclipse, I can hit my service from a browser and get the response that I want.

I am building this container:

```
FROM java:8-jre
VOLUME /tmp
RUN mkdir -p /conf
COPY application.properties /conf/application.properties
ADD target/chrisbolton_service-1.0.0.jar app.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar","--spring.config.location=file:/conf/application.properties"]
```

I am starting my `spring boot` app by using this

`docker run -it --name chrisbolton_service --link chrisbolton:mysql -p 8080:8080 chrisbolton_service`

Also, I have `mysql` running. From `docker ps` you can see,

`bcb0a900b693        mysql:latest        "docker-entrypoint..."   6 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   chrisbolton`

I have [read](https://g00glen00b.be/docker-spring-boot/) that I need to link my containers. However, when I hit my endpoint `localhost:8080/blogs` I am getting

```
2017-08-29 20:20:37.516 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

**UPDATE:**

From the suggestion in the comments, I created a `docker network` and I am running both `mysql` and my `spring boot` app in the network. Still getting the same error as above.

Here is my `inspect` on my `docker network`

`$ docker network inspect chrisbolton
[
    {
        "Name": "chrisbolton",
        "Id": "394e6e207ab53967f6f15e9498c95e5b25f3827ad865cc3c21873c7de2e25465",
        "Created": "2017-08-29T20:37:11.136108745Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "1556dae62334250b20220b05dc18365d65e498c66a47d0db4b8e7e61de8d3496": {
                "Name": "chrisbolton_service",
                "EndpointID": "4ce1a129277a0c27b07be796c4b2fa18604f19764e28124729af2479da0cd58c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "6d7faf5f43722667bdd9080a41f56d9934574900aec1be96118d9683b99f846e": {
                "Name": "chrisbolton",
                "EndpointID": "312b00c24979fdf5bad50377cf64eeec29bbdcbbf5221b981693886ae53ef490",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]`

Comment: I'd recommend using docker networks instead of links. Linking is considered deprecated.

Comment: so is this creating a network and then running both containers on the same network?

Comment: That's correct. Given the above edit, what is your spring boot app trying to connect to for mysql? What's the hostname/ip you are using?

Comment: the mysql instance is running on `localhost:3306`. I am trying to connect and query a table. So in my spring properties, I am connecting to `localhost:3306/chrisbolton`. Before I containerized it, this was working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each container runs in its own networking namespace. Localhost in a container is different from localhost on your host. To connect container to container:

1. Create a common network, e.g. `docker network create myapp`
2. Create your containers with a name and attached to the network, e.g.: `docker run --network myapp --name mysql mysql` for the database. Note that it is not necessary to publish the port on the host or expose the port in your Dockerfile for container-to-container networking to work.
3. The service (the database, webserver, etc) must be listening on all interfaces, not localhost. The syntax for this is `0.0.0.0` to indicate you want to listen on all interfaces.
4. From your application, connect using docker's built in DNS to the name of your other container, e.g. `mysql:3306`. Do not connect to localhost (it won't work) or the published port (you're talking directly to the container).

Comment: How do you make the service listen on all interfaces?

Comment: @ChrisBolton You tell the application to listen on `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. The above answer covers the necessary docker steps. There are countless applications you can run inside of docker, each with different configuration files, cli options, environment variables, or other ways to configure them.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!